# how to convert a dataframe to tensor

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I have a dataframe like this:

```
         ids  dim
0         1    2
1         1    0
2         1    1
3         2    1
4         2    2
5         3    0
6         3    2
7         4    1
8         4    2
9         Nan  0
10        Nan  1
11        Nan  0
```

I want to build a tensorflow tensor out of it so that the result look like this:
Here the columns are correspond to the `dim` column in `df`, as we have three distinct value (0, 1,2) the equivalent tensor would have three column.

And the values of the tensor are the associated `id` s in the `df`.

```
1   1   1
Nan 2   2
3   Nan 3
Nan 4   4
```

What I did:

I tried to convert the `df` to a numpy and then convert it to the tensor, however, the result does not look like what I want:

```
tf.constant(df[['ids', 'dim']].values, dtype=tf.int32)
```

Comment: Any help is appreciated :).

Comment: The accepted answer and your desired output are not the same. This may be confusing for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf


df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],
                   [1, 0],
                   [1, 1],
                   [2, 1],
                   [2, 2],
                   [3, 0],
                   [3, 2],
                   [4, 1],
                   [4, 2],
                   [np.nan, 0],
                   [np.nan, 1],
                   [np.nan, 0]], columns=['ids', 'dim'])
dim_array = np.array(df['dim'])
sort = dim_array.argsort()
final = np.array([df.ids[sort]]).reshape((3, 4)).T
final_result = tf.constant(final, dtype=tf.int32) # use tf.float32 to retain nan in tensor
print(final_result)

# <tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
# array([[          1,           1,           1],
#        [          3,           2,           2],
#        [-2147483648,           4,           3],
#        [-2147483648, -2147483648,           4]], 
# dtype=int32)>
```

In tensorflow `nan` will loss by some value.

Comment: Thanks @Exploore X it works nicely. I have a quick question though. When I set `dtype=tf.int32` I see `-2147483648` as some of the elements that I guess its instead of `NAN`. However, when I changed to `dtype=tf.int16` it doesnt show that number. Do you have any idea of why is that?

Comment: Basically `np.nan` is floating number by default is 32bit(4Byte). When you change it to int32 to int16 value of 32 bit cannot placed into 16bit buffer so it will turn into 0.

Comment: To retain `nan` in tensor use `tf.float32` instead of 'tf.int32' or `int16`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.pivot_table()` for a concise computation

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],
                   [1, 0],
                   [1, 1],
                   [2, 1],
                   [2, 2],
                   [3, 0],
                   [3, 2],
                   [4, 1],
                   [4, 2],
                   [np.nan, 0],
                   [np.nan, 1],
                   [np.nan, 0]], columns=['ids', 'dim'])

df['val'] = 1
df = df.pivot_table(index='ids',columns='dim',values='val') 
df = df.multiply(np.array(df.index), axis=0)

tensor = tf.constant(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

try torch

```
item=torch.tensor(df.values)
```